# ESP8266 analogRead() microphone input into playable audio

Tags: arduino, analog, adc, esp8266, microphone

My goal is to record audio using an electret microphone hooked to an analog pin of an ESP8266 (12E) and then be able to play this audio on another device. This is my circuit:
[image: Electret microphone to esp8266]

In order to check the output of the microphone I connected the circuit to the oscilloscope and got this:

[image: Electret microphone is connected to oscilloscope]

In the "gif" above you can see the waves made by my voice when talking to microphone.

Here is my code on the ESP8266:

```
void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print(" ");
}
```

I would like to play the audio with Audacity in order to have an understanding of the result. Therefore, I copied the numbers from the serial monitor and pasted them into the Python code that maps the data to the (-1,1) interval:

```
def mapPoint(value, currentMin, currentMax, targetMin, targetMax):
    currentInterval = currentMax - currentMin
    targetInterval = targetMax - targetMin

    valueScaled = float(value - currentMin) / float(currentInterval)

    return round(targetMin + (valueScaled * targetInterval),5)

class mapper():
    def __init__(self,raws):
        self.raws=raws.split(" ")
        self.raws=[float(i) for i in self.raws]

    def mapAll(self):
        self.mappeds=[mapPoint(i,min(self.raws),max(self.raws),-1,1) for i in self.raws ]
        self.strmappeds=str(self.mappeds).replace(",","").replace("]","").replace("[","")
        return self.strmappeds
```

That takes the string of numbers, maps them on the target interval (-1 ,+1) and returns a space (" ") separated string of data ready to import into the Audacity software (Tools>Sample Data Import and then select the text file including the data.) The result of importing data from almost 5 seconds voice:

[image: data imported into audacity]

That is about half a second and when I play it I hear unintelligible noise. I also tried lower frequencies but there was only noise there, too.

The suspected causes for the problem are:

1. The ESP8266 does not have the capability to read the analog pin fast enough to return meaningful data (which is probably not the case since its clock speed is around 100 MHz.)
2. The way software is gathering the data and outputs it is not the most optimized way (in the loop, Serial.print, etc.)
3. The microphone circuit output is too noisy (which it might be, but as observed from the oscilloscope test, my voice has to make a difference in the audio output, which was not audible in Audacity.)

4- The way I mapped and prepared the data for Audacity.

- Is there something else I could try?
- Are there similar projects out there? To my surprise I couldn't find anything which was done transparently.
- What is the right way to do this? It could be a very useful and economic method for recording, transmitting, and analyzing audio.

Comment: The signal of the microphone is at its pin 2 in your schematic, not at its 3.3 V power supply pin. Also, C? blocks DC, and the ESP8266's ADC can't read negative values. Also, you may need a pre-amp to get to the right signal level. Also, what is your sample rate and can the ESP8266 keep up? What is your loop time?

Comment: I think you have pretty good guesses where the problem might be. But the schematics in your question will never give any audio signal to ADC input. Is that an error in schematics drawn, or in the circuit too?

Comment: Show the lines where you initialized the serial port.

Comment: @Justme The schematic uploaded was wrong. I replaced it with the real one I am using.

Comment: @jre it is initialized in void setup{ Serial.begin(115200) }.

Comment: And there lies the problem.

Comment: You also need to consider your sample frequency and jitter. There is little use in a distored signal due to sample jitter. Recording digital audio is much more than sampling an analog input - lots of math involved to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned in the comments that you are using a baud rate of 115200.  That means you can only send 115200 bits per second from the ESP8266 to the PC.

If you were sending binary using 16 bits per sample, then you could send a little more than 7000 samples per second.  That would be enough for a little over 3000 hertz audio bandwidth - you could just barely send voice over that.

What you are doing instead is writing text to the serial port.  It takes one byte to send a zero, but five bytes to send a full sixteen bit value (65535.)  Add in another byte for the space between values, and it takes anywhere from two to six bytes for each sample.

That's anywhere from 16 to 48 bits per sample.  The available audio bandwidth varies from 3000 Hz to 1000 Hz, with random skips and gaps when the serial port buffers fill up.

You need to use a faster baud rate and a simpler coding to get something like a steady stream of audio through the serial port.  You'll have to check the ESP8266 documentation and the Arduino documentation to see if higher data rates are supported.